# Newb Help - Output not matching input

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've just attempted to send some bitcoin between 2 wallets and the amount received in the receiving wallet doesn't match the input, can someone explain why?

Here is the transaction https://blockchain.info/tx/53d1083c08eacf36629f544d19546199029a6fc461215a73a07c7c4adb01a7c2

The input was 0.0032 BTC, the fees were 0.00050278 so I expected to see 0.00269722 hit the receiving wallet. What looks to have happened though is the output was split and I actually received 0.00069722 BTC and the 0.002 BTC has gone to a wallet that I don't recognise.

Can someone shed some light on what's happened? Why the 2 outputs? Looking at my previous transactions it's always been a 1:1 input/output relationship.

I know it's only small amounts but keen to understand whats happened and where I can retrieve that 0.002 BTC.

Cheers

Comment: Which wallet software did you used? Are you sure you entered correct amount to be send to destination address? Is there any chance the second address is your wallet change address?

Comment: Ignore me - I think I've worked out whats happened. I have TrustedCoin 2FA enabled in Electrum and they charge 0.002 BTC every 20 transactions for the service, looks like this was the unlucky transaction.

Comment: That’s a lot of money for service given current btc prices

Comment: Two outputs are typical. One output is the destination address and the other output is what we call a change address.

Answer (score -1):

check your wallet: wallet like jaxx and other have some fees

Answer (score -1):

If you use Electrum, 0.002 BTC was taken as fee for 2FA.